# cmake using GitHub Actions MSYS2

Tags: cmake, azure-devops, github-actions, msys2

I am trying to convert an MSYS2 build from azure pipeline CI (which works) to github actions.

I am now stuck with cmake not being recognised as a command.

[image: MSYS2 Cmake Error]

My current (simplified) yaml is the following:

```
- uses: msys2/setup-msys2@v2
        with:
          msystem: MSYS
          install: >-
            git
            base-devel
            mingw-w64-${{ matrix.arch }}-gcc
            mingw-w64-${{ matrix.arch }}-cmake
          update: true

      - name: Move Checkout
        run: |
          Copy-Item -Path ".\temp" -Destination "C:\_" -Recurse
      - name: CI-Build
        shell: msys2 {0}
        run: |
          cd /C/_
          mkdir build
          cd build
          cmake -DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES='.a' -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/Toolchains/mingw64-x86_64.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'MSYS Makefiles' ..
          make VERBOSE=1 -j4
```

Why is cmake not a recognised command?!

Comment: That YAML can't be formatted right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change `msystem` from `MSYS` to `MINGW64` this is because `MSYS` will target cygwin (which would require the `cmake` package as specified by Alex Reinking).

Specifying `MINGW64` will allow use of the `mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake` package correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the package for CMake is wrong. Here is the list of packages in the [MSYS repository](https://packages.msys2.org/search?t=pkg&q=cmake) that contain `cmake` in the name:

```
cmake
icmake
mingw-w64-cmake
mingw-w64-cmake-doc-qt
mingw-w64-extra-cmake-modules
mingw-w64-python-sphinxcontrib-moderncmakedomain
```

I wager you either want `mingw-w64-cmake` or `cmake`. No value of  `matrix.arch` in `mingw-w64-${{ matrix.arch }}-cmake` will expand to one of the above names.